# Accessing private member function

Tags: c++, data-structures

Good day! In the school project I'm working, bool isFull() and bool isEmpty() should be in private. However in the default code that is given to us, isEmpty is called in the main program. Is there a way for me to access isEmpty

```
//data.h
#pragma once

class IntQueue
{
private:
    int *queueArray;
    int queueSize;
    int front;
    int rear;
    int numItems;
  bool isFull();
  bool isEmpty();
public:
    IntQueue(int);
  ~IntQueue();
  void enqueue(int);
  void dequeue(int &);
  void clear();  
};
```

```
//main.cpp
while (!iQueue.isEmpty())
    {
        int value;
    try{
        iQueue.dequeue(value);
     }
    catch(const std::invalid_argument) {
    cout << "Exception occurred: Queue Underflow!" << endl;
     }
        cout << value << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure that `isFull` and `isEmpty` should not be `public` ? Having them `private` looks rather odd (even without considering the problem in `main`)

Comment: Maybe `isFull` should call smth like private `isFullImpl`, but it is really odd.

Comment: can you quote the assignment literally? Could be that you misunderstood something

Comment: ikr but my prof gave us an instruction that those two should be set in private :((

Comment: "Make the isFull and isEmpty member functions private."

Comment: did you write `main.cpp`? if yes add new function like @Nederes propose: `isFullImpl` and change main to `while (!iQueue.isEmptyImpl())`

Comment: solving problems often requires to make compromises between contradicting requirements. If the prof told you to make them private and gave you a main that needs them public, then the thing to do is: make them public

Comment: Maybe `enqueue(int)` and `dequeue(int&)` should return `bool` so you know when insertion/extraction failed and when to leave the `while()`

Comment: Either way, the point is you cannot access `isEmpty` like in your code snippets. Clarify the assignment with your prof or use hacks to satisfy requirements like `#define private public` :)

Comment: I created another function to call isEmpty and it worked @Nederes and  Krzysztof Mochocki  !! Thank you so much :))